# Apply same formatting to Textbox (report title) to All ssrs reports in solution /multiple solutions

Tags: reporting-services

I am not sure is this proper forum to ask. I have multiples solutions for SSRS reports in Visual Studio 2016/17. I am required to modify formatting values (font size and txt color) for all the reports in all the solutions with same value to make it standard. Is there any way I can achieve this in one go (or with least amount of effort  rather than opening each report and modify one by one.)

Thanks

Comment: Get Visual Studio Code (100% free) if you don't have it.Open the root folder that contains all your solutions then you can do a "find and replace in files" (something like Ctrl+Shift+F). That should cover most things. I've done this in the past when company standard font was changed.

Comment: Thanks Alan, this information was helpful.